# Use service in class MVC with Unity Ioc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unity-container, ioc-container

I have application MVC use Unity Ioc.

Declare and init service:

```
public static void Initialize()
{
    IUnityContainer container = BuildUnityContainer();
    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));
}
private static IUnityContainer BuildUnityContainer()
{
    IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
    container.RegisterType<ImyService, myService>(new HttpContextLifetimeManager<ImyService>());;
    return container;
}
```

In class i use code bellow:

```
var service = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ImyService>();
```

This is file **UnityControllerFactory.cs**

```
public override object GetValue()
{
    var assemblyQualifiedName = typeof(T).AssemblyQualifiedName;
    if (assemblyQualifiedName != null)
        return HttpContext.Current.Items[assemblyQualifiedName];
    return null;
}
```

When i running application, it return error at:  *HttpContext.Current.Items[assemblyQualifiedName];*

Error:

> Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.

How to i can using service in my class. Thanks!

Comment: Does the same thing happen if you inject the service into the class constructor?

Comment: @JB06 when i use in controller, it work and not any error. Only use in class, it will error above

Answer (score 0):

the issue here is that the HTTPContext is null when used from a class ( or class library ) like you are trying to do. That's because there is no request to work with. When you use it from a controller everything works because the controller is hit as part of a request so you're golden there.

You could update your UnityController Factory class and pass the needed HTTPContext data as a parameter instead, then you can use it when you need to. It complicates things a little bit though.

Note, you more than likely don't need to pass the whole HTTPContext object, just pass the minimum you can get away with.

Comment: Thanks @Andrei Dragotoniu. Sorry, but i not understand your resolver, you can provider for me sample code.